# Database in WPF and Windowformapps

Tags: sql, database, wpf, windows-forms-core

I'm developing applications using either WPF or WindowFormApps that can store and manage database. The question is that how can i create an in-app database or which kind of database should I use that can run whenever I install it on other devices. My application cannot run on other devices since there is no SQL server on that PC and the connectionstring is different also.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Have you looked into SQLite?  Also, there is a distributable product by SAP "Advantage Database Local Server".  The local is for local / stand-alone machine distribution.  I'll try to find link.  The Advantage Database runs via dlls sitting in the execution folder and has .net support as I too work with it within C#/WPF world and works fine.

[Found this page](https://www.sap.com/products/advantage-database-server/trial.html) for the download.  ADS = Advantage Database SERVER.  ALS is Advantage LOCAL server.

[Another blog post with link about distribution of ALS](https://blogs.sap.com/2016/02/11/download-of-the-ads-als-and-developer-kit-for-version-12/)

Comment: Thanks a lot, that seems work well for me